# Prevent LXC container from remounting host file system

Tags: mount, shutdown, read-only, lxc

Recently, I started looking at LXC as a virtualization platform. I have already created a container, and set it up to use via libvirt.

This works so far, but when I shut down the container, `/var/lib/lxc` (which is on a separate file system) is remounted as ro on the host.

I have already searched for the problem, and found as a solution to drop some capabilities for LXC (e.g. [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165345), it is suggested to drop sys_module, mac_admin and mac_override). However, even if I keep no capabilities at all (lxc.cap.keep=none), the file system is still remounted.

So how to properly prevent a container from randomly remounting file systems on the host?

Answer (score 0):

For LXD/LXC questions you might want to join the LXD/LXC user forum.

The LXD/LXC developers as well as many other experiences LXD/LXC users ask/answer questions like this daily.

Just thought I'd make you aware of it if you weren't.

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/

Brian